# How to upgrade Qt installed in linux from one version to higher

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt4, upgrade

While porting Qt project from windows to linux(ubuntu) i faced with the following issue:

on **windows Qt version 4.8.1** is installed
on **linux 4.6.3** in which some functionalities availiable in higer version 4.8.1 **don`t yet implemented** (ex. **QUdpSocket::joinMultiCastGroup**).

I see only one solution to this problem: upgrade Qt version on linux to 4.8.1.
**How can I do this?**

*On linux I got installed libqt4-dev, qmake.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: I **changed repository** from squeeze (stable) to **wheezy(testing)**, in wheezy latest Qt version is 4.8.1, which is perfectly suits my needs.

Using **package manager** I found **package libqt4-dev** and selected it for **update**.
That is all, the whole process took 5 minutes.

*Disadvantages:*
- As I run Debian on Virtual Box after changing repository I had to reinstall guest additions
- wheezy is less stable than squeeze (I haven`t faced yet with stablilty problem)

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess you can use Upgrade option in the Qt Creator.
2. Or you can download latest version from [Download Qt, the cross-platform application framework](http://qt-project.org/downloads)
3. Or you could try to update using something like `apt-get install(upgrade) libqt4-dev` if you using Debian based system.

Comment: 1. I don`t have Qt Creator and i am not going to install one
2. My question is about how to upgrade Qt, not how to install it from scratch
3. I tried to update it using "apt-get upgrade libqt4-dev", but while updating process goes to the infinit loop of getting package realted to some printer drivers, so this also didn`t help but almost ruined my OS, i said almost because I run it on virtual machine so i simply restored it`s state to previous.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the distro you are using. If there are binary packages for your distro you can update through your package manager. Otherwise you have to download the source of your prefered Qt version and build it yourself.

Comment: Ok, how to find out if packages are availiable and if so update using them?

Comment: I think in Ubuntu you have to use the "software center", but I am not an Ubuntu user. Look at aga's answer.

Comment: and how to do that operations in Debian?

Comment: Aptitude, read the manual. But I doubt Debian has Qt 4.8 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help in your situation, but you can download the Qt Online Installer at the following link:

https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer